# Which F1-score is used for the semantic segmentation tasks?

Tags: computer-vision, semantic-segmentation

I read some papers about state-of-the-art **semantic segmentation** models and in all of them, authors use for comparison F1-score metric, but they did not write whether they use the "micro" or "macro" version of it.

Does anyone know which F1-score is used to describe the segmentation results and why it is so obvious that authors do not define it in papers?

Sample papers:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.00201.pdf

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.00561.pdf

Comment: There is only one F1-score. It is defined as the harmonic mean of precision and recall. See [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-score). You might be thinking of different ways to compute precision and recall? Please elaborate on your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is just one F-1 score - the harmonic mean of precision and recall.

Macro/Micro/Samples/Weighted/Binary are used in the context of multiclass/multilabel targets. If `None`, the scores for each class are returned. Otherwise, this determines the type of averaging performed on the data:

`binary`: Only report results for the class specified by pos_label. This is applicable only if targets (y_{true,pred}) are binary.

`micro`: Calculate metrics globally by counting the total true positives, false negatives and false positives.

`macro`: Calculate metrics for each label, and find their unweighted mean. This does not take label imbalance into account.

`weighted`: Calculate metrics for each label, and find their average weighted by support (the number of true instances for each label). This alters ‘macro’ to account for label imbalance; it can result in an F-score that is not between precision and recall.

`samples`: Calculate metrics for each instance, and find their average (only meaningful for multilabel classification where this differs from accuracy_score)

Segnet paper is discussing different classes accuracy separately in Table#5. So I think they have chosen `None` in this case.